# Post-receive githook to push database to live site

Tags: database, git, hook, bitbucket, githooks

I'm busy workflow with Git. What I want to achieve is pushing a local repository with the database to Bitbucket and then automatically push the files to a server and put the mysqldump file into the database.

I can now make a mysqldump of the database with the git pre-commit hook and push this to my Bitbucket repo. After that I want to handle database import automaticcaly.

I found out that this is possible with the post-receive hook, but can't get it working. Where do I have to add that hook? I tried it in the local git hooks folder where my pre-commit hook is located, but it does nothing.

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a post-commit Webhook from Bitbucket (see [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html)).

To handle the Webhook, you'll need a server that receives it, then pull the changes and executes whatever you want (your database import).

I made a small node app that receives these hooks if you're interested in re-using it: [node-cd](https://github.com/A21z/node-cd)